# Remove "problem" tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are currently 6 questions tagged with [problem](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem). A couple of them are basically just homework problems, and a couple are along the lines of "help, I have a problem". Aside from one, they all have other, more relevant tags.

Since this tag (which has no tag wiki at this time) doesn't seem to add anything to the questions or provide any meaningful sorting/grouping, should it be destroyed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like an obvious one, even if it was [created by the site's founder](https://money.stackexchange.com/revisions/181/1) :-), so I've just removed it.

Comment: Tag taxonomy was very much a work in progress 10 years ago :D